# Dynamically Updating Excel Gantt Chart from Date Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel to-do list that I use for my everyday tasks and work related tasks. I'd like to automatically have my to-do items show up on my gantt chart with colored cells based on the date ranges in my to-do item.

See image for format:
[image]

Here is my Gantt Chart format. Note that the clipped top row is the full date which I planned to use in xx/xx/xxxx date format.
[image]

As this project grows with more tasks, there is a possibility for things to bog down, so I'm looking for a simple yet efficient way to dynamically update the gantt chart.

I want the item and note to appear in the first two blank columns. Right now I am using a private function on the sheet to que this update every time I change a cell. As seen below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:D100")) Is Nothing Then
        ''Call something
    End If
End Sub
```

Does anyone have lightweight code suggestions to get this done with minimal processing power?

Notes on my existing (to do) sheet:

- items whose due date is prior to today are automatically hidden

Comment: u can try show ur codes to let us view what is it that is inefficient in your code..

Comment: Maybe show an example where the desired output is shown in the Gantt chart. How many items can be present at any one time?  My gut feeling is that all your items from the top should also appear in the bottom from row 5 down but perhaps you want them hidden in both the top and bottom when the Date finish is < today's date? You can certainly use conditional formatting rules based on date ranges to do the colouring and VBA to hide rows.

Comment: The question feels quite broad and i, for one, would find it easier to consider if there was specificity.

Comment: @QHarr. Yup its broad. I think he is facing the problem of sluggish updates from Worksheet_Change if it is written inefficiently. You are right some potential is to use conditional formatting and use VBA to hide rows

Comment: You can create a Gantt chart view with conditional formatting and also display the task names.  There is a tutorial http://www.sheets4work.com/2017/09/how-to-add-task-names-to-gantt-view.html Also you could put a filter on the start date column to hide the before today.  I created a version that has a column that categorises tasks as within the current date range, before the range, after etc and that can then be filtered.